# Данный PPA не поддерживает bionic

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, wine, ppa

Не получается установить ppa:wine/wine-builds помогите решить проблему , не удаётся  установить wine на Linux mint .

Comment: Укажите команды, которые вы использовали, а также возникшие ошибки текстом в вопросе

Comment: и зачем вам какой-то левый древний репозиторий, если в официальном репозитории дистрибутива [всё это есть](http://packages.linuxmint.com/search.php?release=any&section=any&keyword=wine)?

Comment: Как бэ это, вайн лет уже тыщщу как поднял свои репы: https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu